# Using box2d in Codelite IDE

Tags: c++, c++11, mingw, box2d, codelite

**UPDATE**: I've gone through and added some apparently missing dependecies of `<cwchar>` in the files mentioned in the build log. Now I'm down to what appears to be a problem with my cwchar header itself, where it's missing a bunch of declarations. Here's the new build log:

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe -j4 SHELL=cmd.exe -e -f  Makefile
"----------Building project:[ ncrv3 - Debug ]----------"
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/Michael/Documents/temp/ncrv3'
C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe  -c  "C:/Users/Michael/Documents/temp/ncrv3/main.cpp" -g -O0 -Wall -std=c++11 -DSFML_STATIC  -o ./Debug/main.cpp.o -I. -IC:\Users\Michael\Documents\SFML\SFML-2.4.1\include
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\postypes.h:40:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\char_traits.h:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\string:40,
                 from C:/Users/Michael/Documents/temp/ncrv3/main.cpp:4:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:177:11: error: '::wcscat' has not been declared
   using ::wcscat;
           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:178:11: error: '::wcscmp' has not been declared
   using ::wcscmp;
           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:179:11: error: '::wcscoll' has not been declared
   using ::wcscoll;
           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:180:11: error: '::wcscpy' has not been declared
   using ::wcscpy;
           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:181:11: error: '::wcscspn' has not been declared
   using ::wcscspn;
           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:183:11: error: '::wcslen' has not been declared
   using ::wcslen;
           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:184:11: error: '::wcsncat' has not been declared
   using ::wcsncat;
           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:185:11: error: '::wcsncmp' has not been declared
   using ::wcsncmp;
           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:186:11: error: '::wcsncpy' has not been declared
   using ::wcsncpy;
           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:188:11: error: '::wcsspn' has not been declared
   using ::wcsspn;
           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:193:11: error: '::wcstok' has not been declared
   using ::wcstok;
           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:196:11: error: '::wcsxfrm' has not been declared
   using ::wcsxfrm;
           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:204:11: error: '::wcschr' has not been declared
   using ::wcschr;
           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:205:11: error: '::wcspbrk' has not been declared
   using ::wcspbrk;
           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:206:11: error: '::wcsrchr' has not been declared
   using ::wcsrchr;
           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:207:11: error: '::wcsstr' has not been declared
   using ::wcsstr;
           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar: In function 'wchar_t* std::wcschr(wchar_t*, wchar_t)':
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:213:55: error: invalid conversion from 'const wchar_t*' to 'wchar_t*' [-fpermissive]
   { return wcschr(const_cast<const wchar_t*>(__p), __c); }
                                                       ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:212:3: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'wchar_t* std::wcschr(wchar_t*, wchar_t)'
   wcschr(wchar_t* __p, wchar_t __c)
   ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar: In function 'wchar_t* std::wcspbrk(wchar_t*, const wchar_t*)':
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:217:58: error: invalid conversion from 'const wchar_t*' to 'wchar_t*' [-fpermissive]
   { return wcspbrk(const_cast<const wchar_t*>(__s1), __s2); }
                                                          ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:216:3: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'wchar_t* std::wcspbrk(wchar_t*, const wchar_t*)'
   wcspbrk(wchar_t* __s1, const wchar_t* __s2)
   ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar: In function 'wchar_t* std::wcsrchr(wchar_t*, wchar_t)':
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:221:56: error: invalid conversion from 'const wchar_t*' to 'wchar_t*' [-fpermissive]
   { return wcsrchr(const_cast<const wchar_t*>(__p), __c); }
                                                        ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:220:3: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'wchar_t* std::wcsrchr(wchar_t*, wchar_t)'
   wcsrchr(wchar_t* __p, wchar_t __c)
   ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar: In function 'wchar_t* std::wcsstr(wchar_t*, const wchar_t*)':
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:225:57: error: invalid conversion from 'const wchar_t*' to 'wchar_t*' [-fpermissive]
   { return wcsstr(const_cast<const wchar_t*>(__s1), __s2); }
                                                         ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:224:3: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'wchar_t* std::wcsstr(wchar_t*, const wchar_t*)'
   wcsstr(wchar_t* __s1, const wchar_t* __s2)
   ^
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\string:40:0,
                 from C:/Users/Michael/Documents/temp/ncrv3/main.cpp:4:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\char_traits.h: In static member function 'static std::size_t std::char_traits<wchar_t>::length(const char_type*)':
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\char_traits.h:358:26: error: 'wcslen' was not declared in this scope
       { return wcslen(__s); }
                          ^
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [Debug/main.cpp.o] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe: *** [All] Error 2
ncrv3.mk:105: recipe for target 'Debug/main.cpp.o' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/Michael/Documents/temp/ncrv3'
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'All' failed
====1 errors, 4 warnings====
```

**OLD:**

I want to include the Box2d (2.3.0) library in my command-line project, which I'm working on in CodeLite 9.2.8. There's nothing in Box2d's documentation about codelite support.

Because there's no relevant setup instructions, I tried taking the entire library (Box2D-Master/Box2D/Box2D) and placing it in my project folder, to dynamically link it. Before I even #include "Box2D/Box2D.h", I get 8 warnings leading to one error in the build. What am I doing wrong?

It looks like some declarations are missing, but I have the entire Box2D library here.
There are also some invalid conversions between `const wchar*` and `wchar*`.

In my compiler settings, I HAVE enabled c++11 support with `-std=c++11`. Here is my entire build log.

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe -j4 SHELL=cmd.exe -e -f  Makefile
"----------Building project:[ ncrv3 - Debug ]----------"
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/Michael/Documents/temp/ncrv3'
C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe  -c  "C:/Users/Michael/Documents/temp/ncrv3/Box2D/Dynamics/b2Body.cpp" -g -O0 -Wall -std=c++11 -DSFML_STATIC  -o ./Debug/Box2D_Dynamics_b2Body.cpp.o -I. -IC:\Users\Michael\Documents\SFML\SFML-2.4.1\include
C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe  -c  "C:/Users/Michael/Documents/temp/ncrv3/Box2D/Dynamics/b2World.cpp" -g -O0 -Wall -std=c++11 -DSFML_STATIC  -o ./Debug/Box2D_Dynamics_b2World.cpp.o -I. -IC:\Users\Michael\Documents\SFML\SFML-2.4.1\include
C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe  -c  "C:/Users/Michael/Documents/temp/ncrv3/Box2D/Dynamics/b2WorldCallbacks.cpp" -g -O0 -Wall -std=c++11 -DSFML_STATIC  -o ./Debug/Box2D_Dynamics_b2WorldCallbacks.cpp.o -I. -IC:\Users\Michael\Documents\SFML\SFML-2.4.1\include
C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe  -c  "C:/Users/Michael/Documents/temp/ncrv3/Box2D/Collision/b2BroadPhase.cpp" -g -O0 -Wall -std=c++11 -DSFML_STATIC  -o ./Debug/Box2D_Collision_b2BroadPhase.cpp.o -I. -IC:\Users\Michael\Documents\SFML\SFML-2.4.1\include
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\postypes.h:40:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\char_traits.h:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\string:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\random:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:66,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\algorithm:62,
                 from ./Box2D/Collision/b2BroadPhase.h:25,
                 from ./Box2D/Dynamics/b2ContactManager.h:22,
                 from ./Box2D/Dynamics/b2World.h:25,
                 from C:/Users/Michael/Documents/temp/ncrv3/Box2D/Dynamics/b2World.cpp:19:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:177:11: error: '::wcscat' has not been declared
   using ::wcscat;
           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:178:11: error: '::wcscmp' has not been declared
   using ::wcscmp;
           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:179:11: error: '::wcscoll' has not been declared
   using ::wcscoll;
           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:180:11: error: '::wcscpy' has not been declared
   using ::wcscpy;
           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:181:11: error: '::wcscspn' has not been declared
   using ::wcscspn;
           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:183:11: error: '::wcslen' has not been declared
   using ::wcslen;
           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:184:11: error: '::wcsncat' has not been declared
   using ::wcsncat;
           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:185:11: error: '::wcsncmp' has not been declared
   using ::wcsncmp;
           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:186:11: error: '::wcsncpy' has not been declared
   using ::wcsncpy;
           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:188:11: error: '::wcsspn' has not been declared
   using ::wcsspn;
           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:193:11: error: '::wcstok' has not been declared
   using ::wcstok;
           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:196:11: error: '::wcsxfrm' has not been declared
   using ::wcsxfrm;
           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:204:11: error: '::wcschr' has not been declared
   using ::wcschr;
           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:205:11: error: '::wcspbrk' has not been declared
   using ::wcspbrk;
           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:206:11: error: '::wcsrchr' has not been declared
   using ::wcsrchr;
           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:207:11: error: '::wcsstr' has not been declared
   using ::wcsstr;
           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar: In function 'wchar_t* std::wcschr(wchar_t*, wchar_t)':
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:213:55: error: invalid conversion from 'const wchar_t*' to 'wchar_t*' [-fpermissive]
   { return wcschr(const_cast<const wchar_t*>(__p), __c); }
                                                       ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:212:3: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'wchar_t* std::wcschr(wchar_t*, wchar_t)'
   wcschr(wchar_t* __p, wchar_t __c)
   ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar: In function 'wchar_t* std::wcspbrk(wchar_t*, const wchar_t*)':
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:217:58: error: invalid conversion from 'const wchar_t*' to 'wchar_t*' [-fpermissive]
   { return wcspbrk(const_cast<const wchar_t*>(__s1), __s2); }
                                                          ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:216:3: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'wchar_t* std::wcspbrk(wchar_t*, const wchar_t*)'
   wcspbrk(wchar_t* __s1, const wchar_t* __s2)
   ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar: In function 'wchar_t* std::wcsrchr(wchar_t*, wchar_t)':
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:221:56: error: invalid conversion from 'const wchar_t*' to 'wchar_t*' [-fpermissive]
   { return wcsrchr(const_cast<const wchar_t*>(__p), __c); }
                                                        ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:220:3: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'wchar_t* std::wcsrchr(wchar_t*, wchar_t)'
   wcsrchr(wchar_t* __p, wchar_t __c)
   ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar: In function 'wchar_t* std::wcsstr(wchar_t*, const wchar_t*)':
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:225:57: error: invalid conversion from 'const wchar_t*' to 'wchar_t*' [-fpermissive]
   { return wcsstr(const_cast<const wchar_t*>(__s1), __s2); }
                                                         ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:224:3: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'wchar_t* std::wcsstr(wchar_t*, const wchar_t*)'
   wcsstr(wchar_t* __s1, const wchar_t* __s2)
   ^
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\postypes.h:40:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\char_traits.h:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\string:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\random:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:66,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\algorithm:62,
                 from ./Box2D/Collision/b2BroadPhase.h:25,
                 from C:/Users/Michael/Documents/temp/ncrv3/Box2D/Collision/b2BroadPhase.cpp:19:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:177:11: error: '::wcscat' has not been declared
   using ::wcscat;
           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:178:11: error: '::wcscmp' has not been declared
   using ::wcscmp;
           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:179:11: error: '::wcscoll' has not been declared
   using ::wcscoll;
           ^
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\string:40:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\random:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:66,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\algorithm:62,
                 from ./Box2D/Collision/b2BroadPhase.h:25,
                 from ./Box2D/Dynamics/b2ContactManager.h:22,
                 from ./Box2D/Dynamics/b2World.h:25,
                 from C:/Users/Michael/Documents/temp/ncrv3/Box2D/Dynamics/b2World.cpp:19:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\char_traits.h: In static member function 'static std::size_t std::char_traits<wchar_t>::length(const char_type*)':
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\char_traits.h:358:26: error: 'wcslen' was not declared in this scope
       { return wcslen(__s); }
                          ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:180:11: error: '::wcscpy' has not been declared
   using ::wcscpy;
           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:181:11: error: '::wcscspn' has not been declared
   using ::wcscspn;
           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:183:11: error: '::wcslen' has not been declared
   using ::wcslen;
           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:184:11: error: '::wcsncat' has not been declared
   using ::wcsncat;
           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:185:11: error: '::wcsncmp' has not been declared
   using ::wcsncmp;
           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:186:11: error: '::wcsncpy' has not been declared
   using ::wcsncpy;
           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:188:11: error: '::wcsspn' has not been declared
   using ::wcsspn;
           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:193:11: error: '::wcstok' has not been declared
   using ::wcstok;
           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:196:11: error: '::wcsxfrm' has not been declared
   using ::wcsxfrm;
           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:204:11: error: '::wcschr' has not been declared
   using ::wcschr;
           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:205:11: error: '::wcspbrk' has not been declared
   using ::wcspbrk;
           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:206:11: error: '::wcsrchr' has not been declared
   using ::wcsrchr;
           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:207:11: error: '::wcsstr' has not been declared
   using ::wcsstr;
           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar: In function 'wchar_t* std::wcschr(wchar_t*, wchar_t)':
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:213:55: error: invalid conversion from 'const wchar_t*' to 'wchar_t*' [-fpermissive]
   { return wcschr(const_cast<const wchar_t*>(__p), __c); }
                                                       ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:212:3: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'wchar_t* std::wcschr(wchar_t*, wchar_t)'
   wcschr(wchar_t* __p, wchar_t __c)
   ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar: In function 'wchar_t* std::wcspbrk(wchar_t*, const wchar_t*)':
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:217:58: error: invalid conversion from 'const wchar_t*' to 'wchar_t*' [-fpermissive]
   { return wcspbrk(const_cast<const wchar_t*>(__s1), __s2); }
                                                          ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:216:3: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'wchar_t* std::wcspbrk(wchar_t*, const wchar_t*)'
   wcspbrk(wchar_t* __s1, const wchar_t* __s2)
   ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar: In function 'wchar_t* std::wcsrchr(wchar_t*, wchar_t)':
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:221:56: error: invalid conversion from 'const wchar_t*' to 'wchar_t*' [-fpermissive]
   { return wcsrchr(const_cast<const wchar_t*>(__p), __c); }
                                                        ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:220:3: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'wchar_t* std::wcsrchr(wchar_t*, wchar_t)'
   wcsrchr(wchar_t* __p, wchar_t __c)
   ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar: In function 'wchar_t* std::wcsstr(wchar_t*, const wchar_t*)':
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:225:57: error: invalid conversion from 'const wchar_t*' to 'wchar_t*' [-fpermissive]
   { return wcsstr(const_cast<const wchar_t*>(__s1), __s2); }
                                                         ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:224:3: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'wchar_t* std::wcsstr(wchar_t*, const wchar_t*)'
   wcsstr(wchar_t* __s1, const wchar_t* __s2)
   ^
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\string:40:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\random:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:66,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\algorithm:62,
                 from ./Box2D/Collision/b2BroadPhase.h:25,
                 from C:/Users/Michael/Documents/temp/ncrv3/Box2D/Collision/b2BroadPhase.cpp:19:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\char_traits.h: In static member function 'static std::size_t std::char_traits<wchar_t>::length(const char_type*)':
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\char_traits.h:358:26: error: 'wcslen' was not declared in this scope
       { return wcslen(__s); }
                          ^
C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe  -c  "C:/Users/Michael/Documents/temp/ncrv3/Box2D/Collision/b2CollideCircle.cpp" -g -O0 -Wall -std=c++11 -DSFML_STATIC  -o ./Debug/Box2D_Collision_b2CollideCircle.cpp.o -I. -IC:\Users\Michael\Documents\SFML\SFML-2.4.1\include
C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe  -c  "C:/Users/Michael/Documents/temp/ncrv3/Box2D/Collision/b2CollideEdge.cpp" -g -O0 -Wall -std=c++11 -DSFML_STATIC  -o ./Debug/Box2D_Collision_b2CollideEdge.cpp.o -I. -IC:\Users\Michael\Documents\SFML\SFML-2.4.1\include
C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe  -c  "C:/Users/Michael/Documents/temp/ncrv3/Box2D/Collision/b2CollidePolygon.cpp" -g -O0 -Wall -std=c++11 -DSFML_STATIC  -o ./Debug/Box2D_Collision_b2CollidePolygon.cpp.o -I. -IC:\Users\Michael\Documents\SFML\SFML-2.4.1\include
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [Debug/Box2D_Collision_b2BroadPhase.cpp.o] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
ncrv3.mk:190: recipe for target 'Debug/Box2D_Collision_b2BroadPhase.cpp.o' failed
ncrv3.mk:174: recipe for target 'Debug/Box2D_Dynamics_b2World.cpp.o' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [Debug/Box2D_Dynamics_b2World.cpp.o] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe: *** [All] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/Michael/Documents/temp/ncrv3'
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'All' failed
====1 errors, 8 warnings====
```

Comment: I've added an apparently missing `<cwchar>` dependency for some of the headers mentioned in the build log. Now they're all gone, and I'm down to what appears to be an error with the cwchar file itself. There are a ton of missing declarations?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem, but it's more of a workaround than an actual fix. All functionality is restored by switching from `-std=c++11` to `-std=gnu++11`. So if you have a similar problem, try switching.